# Routing between apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Can anyone help how to provide routing between different apps....we are basically looking for If we add another app in our application, the integration process should be simple and previous code should not disturb....for example...I am searching for electronics(main app) selected laptop(different app) or monitor(another app)..should be able to route from monitor app to laptop app.. I tried working with different ng-controller

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when("/students", {
        controller: "studentController",
        templateUrl: "app/components/student/students.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/addstudent", {
        controller: "studentController",
        templateUrl: "app/components/student/addstudent.html"
    });
   /*$routeProvider.when("/addfaculty", {
        controller: "facultyController",
        templateUrl: "app/components/student/addfaculty.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/viewfaculty", {
        controller: "facultyController",
        templateUrl: "app/components/student/viewfaculty.html"
    });*/
    $routeProvider.when("/submenu1", {
        controller: "studentController",
        templateUrl: "app/components/student/submenu1.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/students" });
});

apps.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.when("/addfaculty", {
        controller: "facultyController",
        templateUrl: "app/components/faculty/addfaculty.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/viewfaculty", {
        controller: "facultyController",
        templateUrl: "app/components/faculty/viewfaculty.html"
    });

})
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using multiple apps but only for the purpose of displaying multiple independent views on your page?

If that's the case, you might want to take a look at [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which gives you [multiple and named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) to resolve this issue.